# Online course for Algebra II

Tags: secondary-education, algebra, online-instruction, resource-request

I'm going into highschool. Thanks to an acceleration program at my district, I've already taken Algebra I and Geometry. I am very much a math and physics nerd (take a look at my activity over on MSE and PSE if you wish) and spend a lot of time on my own reading and learning - for example, I've taught myself a decent amount of the basics of single-variable calculus (take a look at my notes on github - my github account is linked in my profile) and some linear algebra.

I'd like to take some math classes over the summer (online) in a way that my highschool would be likely to accept them - i.e., I want to take Algebra II this summer, but I don't really want to take it again this fall =) I'd also prefer the course to not be super expensive, as I will probably be paying for it myself.

Thanks, and I apologize if this is not the right site, but I saw similar-ish questions here.

Comment: You might consider seeing if your local community college has any offerings. "College Algebra" is usually quite similar to Algebra 2 and actual college credit may make convincing your high school a little easier. Also, consider doing something else. For example, math camp: http://www.ams.org/programs/students/emp-mathcamps

Comment: @Adam unfortunately, the math camps listed there are rather far away from where I'm at, which is in the midwest. I checked my local community college's offerings - all math classes started before school ended for me. I also checked a university near me's offerings - again, the start dates were earlier than I could manage.

Comment: I found this website to be helpful -- http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/

Comment: I assume you live in the United States.  It might be helpful if you could specify what state you live in, as some states may offer discounted or free online courses for students enrolled in their public schools.

Comment: @mweiss I'm located in Iowa.

Answer (score 5):

This won't help the OP for the summer of 2017, but let me put this here for future readers of this site:

[Michigan Virtual High School](http://www.mivhs.org/high-school-courses) is (as I write these words) developing its own online Algebra 2 curriculum.  The curriculum, which is expected launch in September 2017, consists of two separate half-courses (Algebra 2A and Algebra 2B) which can be taken independently.  I think very highly of the Algebra 2B curriculum, as I happen to the person writing it.

Answer (score 5):

The folks at [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/course/intermediate-algebra) have what you need. It's not cheap ($559), but they work with many students like you, and are highly recommended. I think you will find it worth what it costs, if you can afford that. (And if not, ask them for a scholarship. I don't know if they'd do it or not...)

Answer (score 4):

The [Florida Virtual School](https://www.flvs.net/) offers high school level classes in all subjects, including Algebra 2, and is very well regarded.  They're considered a school district within the Florida school system so I would expect a course from them to be considered acceptable by another public or private high school.  If you [don't live in Florida](https://www.flvs.net/options), you can still take classes there but I believe they charge a fee.  I'm not sure how much it is or if it would be in your price range.

Comment: I looked at their Algebra II course...all was promising, until I saw the price tag, which is $800. A bit much, unfortunately.

Comment: these days, $800 for a course seems pretty cheap.